# Photo item response in Venue detail missing url

Tags: url, foursquare, photos

Not sure if this is a recent change that has not been posted in the change log. I dont see the "url" field in the response for photos.item to https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/photos

as per the documentation in:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo

The current response contains a prefix/suffix - and concatenating them does not give me a url that works:

{

```
id: "4fd2d8ebe4b0191b9baa0f27"
createdAt: 1339218155
source: {
    name: "Instagram"
    url: "http://instagram.com"
}
prefix: "https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/general/"
suffix: "/6HAKqu62Rs08SA91kcigymvft2D3NliwE12D0JtJWbo.jpg"
width: 612
height: 612
user: {
    id: "579544"
    firstName: "Nick"
    lastName: "J."
    photo: {
        prefix: "https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/"
        suffix: "/VDJ3TVMKB03IGDYD.jpg"
    }
}
visibility: "public"
```

}

Comment: I was able to get this to work by contenating the prefix and suffix with "original" in between like so : https://irs3.4sqi.net/img/general/original//6HAKqu62Rs08SA91kcigymvft2D3NliwE12D0JtJWbo.jpg. Looks like the API documentation needs to be updated on the prefix and suffix format for the url

Comment: Got the same problem with the profile pic of a user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967413/how-to-get-profile-pic-for-foursquare-user-based-on-the-object

Answer (score 3):

There are two other questions about the same issue: 
[how to get profile pic for foursquare user based on the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967413/how-to-get-profile-pic-for-foursquare-user-based-on-the-object)

[Foursquare API for venue user image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error)

These are changes they made at the 20120609 update, either use the fix suggested here ([prefix]/original/[suffix]) or lower the version number (the 'v' parameter)

Foursquare will probably release some documentation about this soon.