# Photo error on foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

2 or 3 weeks ago, I had a app which use the photo of a connected foursquare user. I've tested it again today, and looks like the API has changed. I use the endpoint

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/

Now, the photo attribute in json contains to json attribute : prefix and suffix.
Here's my problem : when I try to  concatenate these strings, I got a "internal server error".
You can try it here :
https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/TLBKJFDZJ504Y5DO.jpg

Is it a bug, or am I do it in the wrong way ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen the similar question/answer posted earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error -- I believe it addresses your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !
Maybe Foursquare can make the message a little more user(/developer)-friendly.

Comment: There were a lot of changes with v=20120609, we'll be going through and updating all the documentation soon.

Answer (score 3):

For quick reference, add size in between:

```
prefix + SIZE + suffix
```

Eg. https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/100x100/TLBKJFDZJ504Y5DO.jpg

For sizes see https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo