# Foursquare API returns invalid avatar url?

Tags: foursquare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Foursquare API for venue user image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error)

I first noticed this problem with the avatars a few weeks ago. I thought it would be a temporary issue, but I noticed today it's still not working correctly.

The data returned from the API request contains a url like this for the avatar -> https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/YEM5TK441NXU2QTJ.jpg

But when you try actually open the image it shows "The image “https://irs1.4sqi.net/img/user/YEM5TK441NXU2QTJ.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors." ?

Why would the Foursquare API return an invalid url? Any one else having this problem? How would I be able to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if you open the link via the browser you will see that you are getting "Internal Error".

This is the same issue as described here: [Foursquare API for venue user image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error)

Which is caused by changes made to the API earlier this month.

You should register to this google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foursquare-api/MpNpdO5zARU