# foursquare "image" URL returns Internal server error

Tags: api, foursquare, avatar

everything seems to work in my app, but the "blank" avater, 4sq returns https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/blank_boy.png but that link is broken... I am using the latest version of the API. has anyone found a fix for this?

```
photo =     {
    prefix = "https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/";
    suffix = "/blank_boy.png";
};
```

(that's the response from the server)

thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error/10981046#10981046 has 2 answers that solve this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed by the comment from @Jonathan Levison you need to specify the "dimensions" between the prefix and suffix values. For example

```
https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/user/100x100/blank_boy.png
```