# Four Square API Application icons

Tags: android, foursquare

In the Fours Square Application, The checkin module shows icons for the places near me, like Business Schools, eating places etc. Now i am integrating Fours Square API in my application, and would like a similar look and feel. Can anyone tell me where i can get these icons from, or will i have to get my own designed.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Category icons are returned by the API when returning a venue. Look at the icon stanza within the venue's category for a returned venue. [Foursquare API for venue user image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977100/foursquare-api-for-venue-user-image-error) contains instructions on how to construct the icon from the prefix/suffix.